# Does WSO2 DSS support Memcache and redis?

Tags: nosql, redis, memcached, wso2, wso2-data-services-server

As far as I know, WSO2 DSS has support some of NoSQL DB, such as Cassandra and MongoDB.

I have no idea whether DSS support Memcache and redis?

If DSS does not support them until now, 
when will it support them? 
Is there a plan to support them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, we do not support Memcache or Redis, and does not have any immediate plans to support them out of the box. But you can easily write custom data source adaptors to support this, for me information, check http://docs.wso2.org/display/DSS310/Custom+Data+Sources.

Cheers,
Anjana.